# Creating bridged/forwarding proxies/tunnels via an intermediate machine to get around a VPN block to connect to a work machine

Tags: networking, ssh, vpn, proxy, ssh-tunnel

I'm not sure if my question makes sense, but I'll try to describe what I'm trying to do.

I have three machines A, B, and C. A is a work machine that is not exposed to the outside world. B is my machine at home that has SSH access, and A is able to SSH to B. I am able to connect to A from B if I connect to my work's VPN. C is a laptop I use on my university's network. Essentially I have the following:

```
+----VPN-----+
|            |
V            |
A----SSH---->B<--SSH--C
```

My university blocks all VPN connections and so I am not able to VPN to work. I was wondering if there was some way I could get around this block to be able to access my work machine?

Is there a way to "forward" a VPN connection, or perhaps set up a tunnel via machine B so that C can get to A? One rather convoluted idea I had was to set up a proxy on A to itself, forward the proxy port to B via an SSH connection, and then set up a tunnel from C to B via SSH to forward a local port to the proxy port on B. However, I wasn't really able to do the remote port forwarding once I had the proxy set up (SSH would just hang).

Is there a way to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

I think that as long as you maintain VPN connection between A & B you should be able to connect using ssh proxy magic.

Looks like this shall work for you:

```
foo@C:~ $ ssh -o ProxyCommand="ssh -W %h:%p <B>" <A>
```

This can be achieved also without VPN by maintaining permanent ssh connection from A to B with remote port forwarding

```
foo@A:~ $ ssh -R 2222:localhost:22 B # ensure that this connection is up forever

foo@C:~ $ ssh -o ProxyCommand="ssh -W localhost:2222 <B>" <A>
```

More hacks here:
https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSSH/Cookbook/Proxies_and_Jump_Hosts